# Change background image of division while changing src of image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a style specified in the head of my document. I specify the background image on a division but later on a need to change it if the user clicks on a link but everything I've tried to do refuses to work.

```
<style type="text/css">
            /*Some CSS*/
            .large {
                background: url('/images/artwork1.jpg') no-repeat;
}
</style>

<div class="large"></div>
<img id="main_image" alt="Image"/>
<img onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('main_image').sr‌​c='/images/artwork2.‌​jpg'; $('.large').css({'background-image':'url(/images/artwork2.jp‌​g)';" alt="Change Image"/>
```

I tried taking the background image out of the style but clicking on a link didn't change it. I've tried JavaScript and jQuery. I was able to change the image until I added in the jQuery.

Comment: create a method.very unreadable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, that's because you have error in your syntax.

Try this.

`javascript:document.getElementById('main_image').sr‌​c='/images/artwork2.‌​jpg'; $('.large').css('background-image', 'url(/images/artwork2.jp‌​g)');`

Comment: That didn't make any difference.

Comment: Nothing. It didn't show any messages on the console at all.

Comment: I had a  couple of question marks in the code that shouldn't be there. I don't know how they got there but now they're gone, it's working perfectly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Beside you have some syntax problems, you should really encapsulate your JS in a function, and not put everything in the `onclick` event attribute! Or use just jQuery to register a listener.

Speaking of jQuery: Why are you mixing plain JS with jQuery selectors? If you have jQuery already available you can use it!

```js
function myFunction() {
    $("#main_image").attr("src", "https://dummyimage.com/150x100/ff0000/fff");
    $(".large").css("background-image", "url(https://dummyimage.com/150x100/ff0000/fff)");
};
```

```css
div, img  {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.large {
  background: url('https://dummyimage.com/150x100/000000/fff') no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="large"></div>
<img id="main_image" alt="Image" />
<button onclick="myFunction()">change image</button>
```